# Steam UI not launching after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: steam

Steam process is showing in System Monitor, but UI is not launching.

Comment: I experience this behavior from time to time with steam, usually it is because the graphics drivers and/or libs were updated, then I just need to reboot and it starts working again. Maybe you can try different graphic drivers as well. If still does not works then [edit] your question with some logs, if your try and start steam from the terminal by typing `steam` it will print out the logs.

Comment: @Eduardo I would advice caution with suggestions like "try different graphics drivers" because (1) with Intel or AMD GPUs there are no user installable drivers (well, technically there are for AMD but regular users SHOULDN'T try the proprietary overlay) and (2) with Nvidia there are choices but usually only one version is recommended and since years ago Ubuntu install it automatically if that option is selected.

Comment: @Eduardo yeah, it seems to be solved now. I did change the graphics from nvidia-510 to nvidia-470 and removed all old directories and installed steam via wget http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb. Earlier many reinstalls did not fix this issue. The graphics driver did!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Issue seems to be solved now. I changed the graphics from nvidia-510 to nvidia-470 in Software and Updates.

I removed earlier installs:

```
sudo apt remove steam steam-launcher steam-installer
sudo apt purge steam steam-launcher steam-installer

sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/steam
sudo rm -rf ~/.steam
sudo rm ~/.steampath
sudo rm ~/.steamid
sudo rm -rf Steam
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/steam
```

Then installed steam via wget

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt update
sudo apt install wget gdebi-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386

wget -O ~/steam.deb http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb

sudo gdebi ~/steam.deb
```

Then ran steam via terminal

```
steam
```

This solved my problem!

P.S.

Also, when I ran steam through terminal, an error was shown:

> Could not connect to X session manager: None of the authentication
> protocols specified are supported

For this, a solution was mentioned on the steam website to check $DISPLAY

```
echo $DISPLAY
DISPLAY=:0 steam
```

Don't have much idea what this is (I AM NEW to Ubuntu and anything open-source). This might help if nothing above this helps.

Comment: this solution still worked for me but had to remove `sudo apt remove steam-devices` too

Comment: Worked for me too!
The version installed with aptitude seems to be really outdated

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you!

Comment: Since an edit must be at least 6 characters, whereas I only want to add one, I'm posting this as a comment instead: the directory is not `…/steamid/`, but `…/steampid/`. Elsewise a flawless solution!

Comment: this did not work form, how do I uninstall this version again? I would like to try the snap version...

Comment: the first 2 lines are what removes it.  I had to uninstall and reinstall 2x before it worked for me

Comment: Thank you kind sir.

Comment: Always run the steam inside the terminal. In my case, if I don't run in the `steam` command in the terminal, I will get blinking Steam windows which can only be killed.

Comment: But that is not user-friendly. I don't like using the terminal for small tasks like launching any app.

Answer (score 7):

After my Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade to 22.04, I noticed invoking steam from the launchbar produced only black windows, but worked from the terminal.
I run Nvidia full time (external GPU on a laptop), no prime switching back to Intel for any reason.

Edited the /usr/share/applications/steam.desktop and changed the PrefersNonDefaultGPU=true to false.  My default is Nvidia, so why would I want the Intel?  Maybe a bug.

---

The settings/power option "performance" should set the Nvidia GPU as the default.  With a laptop hybrid setup, the Intel GPU handles the display, and in the output of:

```
xrandr --listproviders
```

the Intel GPU should have "Sink Output, Source Offload". If things are otherwise, you may fix things per program with:

__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 \ __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia

Comment: Have the same situation and nvidia set to on-demand, but changing this option doesn't seem to work for me.  Any ideas for us eGPU users?

Comment: This was my issue as well. My laptop has an integrated and discrete GPU, and setting `PrefersNonDefaultGPU=false` in the launcher fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same issue after my Ubuntu Upgrade (from 21.10 to 22.04).

And simply uninstall & re-install it form 'Ubuntu Software' resolved this issue for me.

Though i am unaware of the root cause, i suggest this solution, as you won't have any data loss/not affecting other critical parts of the OS - in this approach. Hope it helps.

Comment: Did not try this. As my issue was solved, I just do want to do anything else to jinx it lol. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal run

```
steam
```

to start it.

A possible reason for steam not launching, might be, that there is already a steam-process running.

Show all processes and filter for "steam"

```
ps ax | grep steam
```

if steam is not working is should showing this:
4378 ?        S      0:00 bash /home/tymon/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh
4574 ?        Zl     0:04 [steam] 
5350 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto steam

the problem is in [steam] defunct.
to fix the problem you need to "kill" the broken process.

type:

```
killall -9 steam
```

for me everything is fixed